# jQuery Sortable update output on input

Tags: jquery, nested-sortable

We're using the [jQuery Sortable](https://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/) library for dynamic menu management similar to WordPress. And it has multi level management.

```
<ol id="my-nav">
    <li data-id="unique-id-here" data-label="">
        <span>My Label</span>
        <input type="text" class="label-change">
        <ol><!-- PLACEHOLDER FOR SUBMENU --></ol>
    </li>
</ol>

<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

We want to update the Menu Label using the inherited input field. So we did something like below:

```
$('body').on('keyup change', '.label-change', function () {
    var this_menu_label_field = $(this);
    var this_field_val        = this_menu_label_field.val();
    var this_menu_nav         = this_menu_label_field.parents('li');

    // Update the text string inside the <li>
    this_menu_nav.find('span').html(this_field_val);

    // Update the data-label attribute
    this_menu_nav.attr('data-label', this_field_val).sortable('refresh');

    var serialized_data = menu_container.sortable('serialize').get();
    $('#output').val(JSON.stringify(serialized_data));
});
```

The code is updating the string inside the `<span>` inside the respective `<li>` and also changing the `data-label`. But unfortunately it's updating only the first keystroke into the `#output` textarea.

For example: if we type "Whatever", it might take "W" or "Wha". And no further keystrokes are updated into the `#output`. But at always the update inside the `<span>` and `data-label` is working fine.

We need this kind of feature critically. But how can we achieve this?

#### DEMO Fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/mayeenulislam/Lsrgu0qy/38/

- Do nothing, see the value in the `<textarea>`
- Do nothing, just type in the textbox
- Now see the value in the `<textarea>` again

Comment: I've inspected your code as well as the demo, but I couldn't understand your problem that should be related to `jQuery-Sortable`. It seems there is no connection between them. You just have some issue to update the text of inputs. Could you explain what is precisely your problem?

Comment: Sorry, the fiddle was buggy - happened while I minimized the code. You can check now with the new link. We want to update the JSON array in the textarea while we're taking input in the text field. But the text inputs are changing the `data-label` of the `<li>` but not the JSON array in the textarea.

Comment: Perhaps this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24377212/jquery-sortable-updated-data-not-being-serialized. It seems related.

Comment: I fiddled around with this and was able to make it work. Check my forked fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/qf7n89oe/. The only change I made was to replace `this_menu_nav.attr('data-label', this_field_val)` with `this_menu_nav.data('label', this_field_val)`. It seems using `attr` causes some caching issues so I replaced with [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) which doesn't seem to have this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fiddled around with this and was able to make it work. Check my forked fiddle here: [jsfiddle.net/qf7n89oe](https://jsfiddle.net/qf7n89oe/).

The only change I made was to replace

```
this_menu_nav.attr('data-label', this_field_val).sortable('refresh');
```

with

```
this_menu_nav.data('label', this_field_val).sortable('refresh');
```

It seems using `attr()` causes some caching issues so I replaced it with [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) which doesn't seem to have this problem.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery Sortable stores data in data object. So it does not process data-* attributes. You can use Kodos Johnson answer if you would like to use jQuery data object. The alternative is to have your own definition of serialization function. See this example:

```js
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * OUR CODE STARTS HERE
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var menu_container = $('#my-nav');
  var menu_data_field = $('#output');

  var sortable = menu_container.sortable({
    delay: 500,
    group: 'serialization',
    onDrop: function($item, container, _super) {
      var data = sortable.sortable('serialize').get();

      var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);

      menu_data_field.val(jsonString);
      _super($item, container);
    },
    serialize: function($parent, $children, parentIsContainer) {
      let result = $parent.map(function(e) {
        let attr = {};
        $.each(this.attributes, function() {
          const name = this.name.replace("data-", "");
          attr[name] = this.value;
        });
        return attr;
      });

      if (parentIsContainer)
        return [$children]
      else if ($children[0]) {
        result[0].children = $children
      }

      delete result.subContainers
      delete result.sortable

      return result.get();
    },
  });

  $('body').on('keyup', '.label-change', function() {
    var this_menu_label_field = $(this);
    var this_field_val = this_menu_label_field.val();
    var this_menu_nav = this_menu_label_field.parent('li');

    // Update the text string inside the <li>
    this_menu_nav.find('> span').html(this_field_val);

    // Update the data-label attribute
    this_menu_nav.attr('data-label', this_field_val).sortable('refresh');

    var serialized_data = menu_container.sortable('serialize').get();
    console.log(serialized_data);
    $('#output').val(JSON.stringify(serialized_data));
  });
});
```

```css
body.dragging,
body.dragging * {
  cursor: move !important;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border-color: red;
}

#my-nav {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#my-nav ol {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

#my-nav li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  color: #333;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  cursor: move;
}

#my-nav li.placeholder {
  position: relative;
  border-style: dashed;
  background-color: #ededed;
  min-height: 34px;
}

#my-nav li.placeholder:before {
  position: absolute;
}

#my-nav li.dragged {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  opacity: .5;
  z-index: 2000;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#my-nav li.dragged i.icon-move {
  color: var(--primary);
}

#my-nav li.highlight {
  background: gray;
  color: lightgray;
}

#my-nav li:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#my-nav i.icon-move {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #999;
  padding: 5px;
}

.dd {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 600px;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.dd-list {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.dd-list .dd-list {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.dd-item,
.dd-empty,
.dd-placeholder {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.dd-handle {
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #fafafa;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dd-handle:hover {
  color: #2ea8e5;
  background: #fff;
}

.dd-item>button {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  width: 25px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.dd-item>button:before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-indent: 0;
}

.dd-item>button.dd-expand:before {
  content: '+';
}

.dd-item>button.dd-collapse:before {
  content: '-';
}

.dd-expand {
  display: none;
}

.dd-collapsed .dd-list,
.dd-collapsed .dd-collapse {
  display: none;
}

.dd-collapsed .dd-expand {
  display: block;
}

.dd-empty,
.dd-placeholder {
  margin: 5px 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 30px;
  background: #f2fbff;
  border: 1px dashed #b6bcbf;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dd-empty {
  border: 1px dashed #bbb;
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  background-size: 60px 60px;
  background-position: 0 0, 30px 30px;
}

.dd-dragel {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.dd-dragel>.dd-item .dd-handle {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.dd-dragel .dd-handle {
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.dd-nochildren .dd-placeholder {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-sortable/0.9.13/jquery-sortable-min.js"></script>

<ol id="my-nav">
  <li data-id="unique-id-here" data-label="My Label">
    <span>My Label</span>
    <input type="text" class="label-change form-control" placeholder="Type here to see the impact">
    <ol>
      <li data-id="unique-id-here" data-label="My Sub Label">
        <span>My Sub Label</span>
        <input type="text" class="label-change form-control" placeholder="Type here to see the impact">
        <ol>
          <!-- PLACEHOLDER FOR SUBMENU -->
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>

<h4>OUTPUT HERE</h4>
<textarea id="output" class="form-control" placeholder="">[[{"label":"My Label","id":"unique-id-here","children":[[{"label":"My Sub Label","id":"unique-id-here","children":[[]]}]]}]]</textarea>
```